# How to assign a dynamic source path for image in flex

Tags: image, apache-flex, dynamic, itemrenderer

I would like to assign a source path to my image dynamically. My paths look something like this

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Opengate\image1.jpg
```

or

```
\\servername\Images\image2.jpg
```

I would like to do the following

```
protected function itemrenderer1_dataChangeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    var xmlColumns:XML = new XML(data.toString());

    for(var x:uint=0; x < (xmlColumns.children()).length(); x++)
    {
         var xml:XML = (xmlColumns.children())[x];
         //Alert.show('' + xml.toString());
         if (xml.name() != 'Xlabel') 
         {
              if(xml.attribute("myField") == String(parentDocument.parentDocument.ImageField))
              {
                   thePath = xml;                   

              }
         }
    }  
}

<s:BitmapImage  source="{thePath}" width="80" height="80"  smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high" />
```

but it doesn't work; `thePath` is equal to something like '\servername\Images\image2.jpg. The only time it works is if the image file is sitting in my project folders. But if it's outside my project, on a server for instance, it doesn't work.

Comment: A Flex application runs on the client, not the server; hence the path of your image must be a URL instead of a physical path on the server (unless you embed the image into the swf at compile time).

Answer (score 0):

try change the path

`\\servername\\Images\\image2.jpg`

for

```
  http://servername/Images/image2.jpg
```